# NumPy 2D matrix: return true row indices where column is true

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays in NumPy:

```
a1 = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
               [1, 1, 0],
               [0, 1, 0],
               [1, 1, 1]])

a2 = np.array([1, 2])
```

and I need to know the indices of the rows of a1 where both column 1 and 2 (given in a2) equal 1.

In the above example this would only be the last row with index 3. It does not matter if other columns equal 1.

Can someone help me get this done without heavy looping?

Comment: a2 shows the columns which have to be equal to 1 in a1

Comment: If `a2 = np.array([0, 1])`, what is the result you want? index 1 and 3 or only index 3?

Comment: in this case the expected result would be 1 and 3, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using simple indexes and `np.all` will give you the rows where all elements are equal to 1 :

```
np.all(a1[:, a2], axis=1)
```

This give you a mask of row matching this criteria. Like this :

```
array([False, False, False,  True])
```

Then following @rahlf23 comment you can use `np.where` to find the indexes matching the criteria like this :

```
np.where(np.all(a1[:, a2], axis=1))[0]
```

**Output** :

```
array([3])
```

Comment: +1 great answer. To return the indices of the `True` elements, just wrap your answer in `np.where()`, therefore `np.where(np.all(a1[:, a2], axis=1))`

Comment: to be precise: `np.where(np.all(a1[:, a2],  axis=1))` produces a tuple where the first element corresponds to the desired array. so one would have to access it  `np.where(np.all(a1[:, a2],  axis=1))[0]`